# C++ type to hold members that can't be initialized in the constructor

Tags: c++

I have some members that can't be initialized at construction time of the container class because the information to construct them is not available. At the moment I'm using `std::unique_ptr` to construct them later when the information becomes available.

The dynamic allocation/indirection is an unnecessary overhead as I *know* they will be constructed eventually. I could use `std::optional`, but I feel the semantics of `std::optional` will make the ones reading the code think the members are somehow optional and they might be missing which is not the case.

Is there any `std` library type that can hold a type for later construction with better semantics than `std::optional`?

EDIT: example code

```
struct Inner
{
    Inner(int someValue)
        : internalValue(someValue)
    {}

    int internalValue;
};

struct Outer
{
    Outer(){/*...*/}

    void createInner(int someValue)
    {
        assert(inner == nullptr);
        inner = std::make_unique<Inner>(someValue);
    }

    // I would like to avoid the dynamic memory allocation here
    std::unique_ptr<Inner> inner;
};
```

Comment: `std::optional` says "the thing at this position may or may not exist right at this moment". It sounds like exactly your use case. If you're exposing this half-initialized construct to the user directly, then I would argue *that* is the part you need to reconsider. If it's just a private member, then make it `std::optional` and put a comment explaining exactly what you just said here, for future readers of the code to see

Comment: `optional` is exactly what you want if you want to avoid dynamic allocation.

Comment: You can always just wrap stuff in an anonymous union. But that means you have to handle destruction yourself too.

Comment: `std::optional` is the way to go. You could also use an anonymous union of `std::array<char, sizeof(YourType)>` and `YourType` together with placement new, if you like that better. (One sensible safety check less, if you later know, the object is constructed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std:::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is what you are looking for, eg:

```cpp
#include <optional>

struct Inner
{
    Inner(int someValue)
        : internalValue(someValue)
    {}

    int internalValue;
};

struct Outer
{
    Outer(){/*...*/}

    void createInner(int someValue)
    {
        inner = Inner(someValue);
    }

    std::optional<Inner> inner;
};
```

If you don't like how `optional` looks in your code, you can simply define an alias to give it a more suitable name for your situation, eg:

```cpp
#include <optional>

struct Inner
{
    Inner(int someValue)
        : internalValue(someValue)
    {}

    int internalValue;
};

template<typename T>
using delayed_create = std::optional<T>;

struct Outer
{
    Outer(){/*...*/}

    void createInner(int someValue)
    {
        inner = Inner(someValue);
    }

    delayed_create<Inner> inner;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best option. I will replace `inner = Inner(someValue);` with `inner.emplace(someValue);`  because my actual types are not movable/copyable

Comment: OP said explicitly they didn't want std::optional.

Comment: @Jellyboy only because of the implied confusion it may cause readers, not because of its actual functionality. The suggested alias addresses that confusion.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a union and placement new.

The advantage of this method is that it is universal. With std::optional you will need a C++17 compiler while with this you can build with any C++  compiler ever known to manhood.

Example:

```cpp
class Inner {
public: 
    Inner() = delete;
    Inner( int val ) : a(val) {}
private: 
    int a;
};

class Outer {
    Outer() {}
    ~Outer() {
        if ( initialized ) {
            inner.~Inner();
            initialized = false;
        }
    }
    Outer( const Outer& ) = delete; // TBI
    Outer( Outer&& ) = delete;  // TBI
    Outer( const Outer&& ) = delete; // TBI
    void create( int x ) {
        if ( not initialized ) {
            initialized = true;
            new ((void*)&inner) Inner(x);
        }
    }
private: 
    bool initialized = false;
    union {
        Inner inner;
    };
};
```

Code above not complete. Needs to fill in the copy/move constructors.

Comment: In this example case it is not required, but it should be noted that if the object in the union does not have trivial constructors/destructor, then those need to be implemented  by hand as well in the union.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes I forgot to do that. Updated.

Comment: If only there were some class that wrapped all this complexity for you so you didn't take the risk that you'd miss a detail and forget to, say, implement `operator=(&&)`.

Comment: That's just `std::optional` with extra steps, but without library convenience functions. If the OP only wants to delay initialization into the c'tor body that bool is pointless. There will always be on object to destruct.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica if the Inner class contains say a std::string and the user never calls create() then the destructor will segfault without the bool.

Comment: Meh. I did not notice the OP's edit. Shame their use case is not the limited one I originally understood. Given that, `std::optional` is superior in every way then.